# Import json not parsing the data

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a json file with all the bonus characteristic you get per level.

Json is like this :

```
{
  "0": {
    "Armor": 1,
    "Strenght": 1,
    "Mana": 2,
    "Power": 1,
    "Health": 1
  },
  "1": {
    "Armor": 1,
    "Strenght": 1
  }
}
```

I then call a loader :

```
struct LevelBonus
{
    int Power;
    int Mana;
    int Strenght;
    int Armor;
    int Health;
}
Dictionary<string, LevelBonus> statsPerLevel;
statsPerLevel = FileLoaderManager.instance.LoadJSONData<Dictionary<string, LevelBonus>>("PlayerStats/level.json");
```

And somewhere else there is

```
public T LoadJSONData<T>(string path)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, path);
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        T loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(dataAsJson);
        return loadedData;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

My Data is loaded, but not parsed correctly. Basically, no error, but no data returned event tho the file is read and until

```
T loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(dataAsJson);
```

I can read the data correctly as string. but that FromJson return nothing

What I am missing ?

EDIT : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1583163/importing-data-from-json.html?childToView=1583169#comment-1583169

Comment: Try making the members of `LevelBonus` public, e.g. `public int Power;`

Comment: sadly doesn't work

Comment: *not parsed correctly* what does that mean exactly?

Comment: Oh yes didn't precise, it means it doesn't return anything, and doesn't get error.

Comment: @Crocsx, did u ever tried with newtonsoft.json.

Comment: no I was looking into some lib today. I fixed it using the one in the EDIT link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I pretty much always do when loading Jsons is never ever write them by hand. I create an instance of of what I'll want to write in memory first, than SAVE to json - to make sure the field layout is exactly as expected by the serialiser - its easy to write a json that is valid, but makes no sens when mapped to a C# class

In your case the answer is simple. in Json structure you have

```
{ field_name : field_value }
```

pairs. But when it says "1":value, it won't ever deserialize, becuase the name of the field is "1", which is not a valid field name in C# (it has to start with a letter). The definition object to which you desrialize would have to look like

```
class MyStats
{
 public int Armor;
 public int Strenght;
 public int Mana;
 public int Power;
 public int Health;
}
```

I imagine this is rougly right, however to deserialize your example, your container object would need to be defined like this (which is invalid)

class MyContainerObject
    {
       public MyStats 1; // ERROR: INVALID FIELD NAME !!
       public MyStats 2; // ERROR: INVALID FIELD NAME !!
    }

It is not returning an error as the Json is valid, and the parser just skips fields that don't match the class definition you are using.

Regading the use of arrays you can either hack a wrapper extension (as suggested by Dharmashree) which is a bit quirky (JsonUtility needs to know the concrete class to which it is deserialising and it can't go directly to array or list so for example:

```
[
    {"a": 1 },
    {"b": 1 },
    {"c": 1 }
]
```

while being a valid json, it will not be parsed by JsonUtility (raw, anonymous array), however this will

```
{
    "MyStats": [
      { "a": 1 },
      { "b": 2 },
      { "c": 1 }
    ]
}
```

you can structure your data to contain the array within a container object, so your main object could be defined as:

```
class MyContainerObject
{
   public MyStats[] stats; 
}
```

Access to your elements is then via myList[index]

Anwyays, I will again highliy recommending starting with WRITING a json representing your structure, checking if that deserialising works as expected, and only then edit the file by hand.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use array of Json. You can follow this sample here.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToObjectComplex.htm

Not able to comment so mentioning in answer.

The Person class used in NewtonSoft Documentation should have following structure.

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I need a custom JSON library cause JsonUtility is very weak

Comment: @Crocsx If this is Unity, then using JSON.Net may be problematic.

Comment: @Dharmashree IF you can't comment, then you need to go and get the required reputation to do so. Please don't try and abuse the system and post an answer.

Comment: this json is not an array